# Prove $II(X,Y) = \langle L(X), Y\rangle = \langle X, L(Y)\rangle$ (Weingarten Map and 2nd fundamental form)

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove $II(X,Y) = \langle L(X), Y\rangle = \langle X, L(Y)\rangle$ where $L$ is the Weingarten map

We know $II(X,Y) =\sum L_{ij} X^i Y^j$

and $X = \sum X^i x_i$ and $Y = \sum Y^j y_j$ and $L = Xn$ where $n$ is the normal vector.

How would we go about proving this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are dealing with surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the equality $II(X,Y)=\langle L(X), Y\rangle$ is by definition:
$$
L(X)=-D_Xn,\quad II(X,Y):=\langle -D_Xn, Y\rangle.
$$
The other equality follows from the symmetry of partial derivatives using
$$L_{ij}=-\frac{\partial\mathbf{n}}{\partial u_i}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial u_j}=\mathbf{n}\cdot\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{x}}{\partial u_i\partial u_j}$$
(the last equality follows from $\mathbf{n}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial u_j}=0$ for $\mathbf{x}(u_1,u_2)$ any parametrisation of the surface).

Comment: whats Dx in this case?

Comment: $D_X$ is the covariant derivative wrt $X$, which is basically your $L=Xn$ except for the sign convention.